# couldn't exec gunicorn_start EACCES

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="trueguild"                                          # Name of the applica$
DJANGODIR=/webapps/trueguild_django/trueguild             # Django project dire$
SOCKFILE=/webapps/trueguild_django/run/gunicorn.sock      # we will communicte $
USER=trueguild                                            # the user to run as

GROUP=webapps                                             # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                             # how many worker pro$
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=trueguild.settings                 # which settings file$
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=trueguild.wsgi                         # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as $NAME"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do$
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
 --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

I have the above gunicorn_start file.But when i start using supervisorctl then it throws this error

```
supervisor: couldn't exec /webapps/trueguild_django/bin/gunicorn_start: EACCES
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

i am using django along with nginx and gunicorn.

How can i start the server using supervisor?

here is the supervisor.d conf file

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

and here is the trueguild.conf file inside conf.d directory

```
[program:trueguild]
command = /webapps/trueguild_django/bin/gunicorn_start                    ; Command to start app
user = trueguild                                                          ; User to run as
stdout_logfile = /webapps/trueguild_django/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log   ; Where to write log messages
redirect_stderr = true                                                ; Save stderr in the same log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8                       ; Set UTF-8 as default encoding
```

Comment: Show Your `supervisord.conf` file (only app section)

Comment: i have included the files@TomaszJakubRup

Answer (score 19):

In the `trueguild.conf` file

add `sh` after command...

it'll be like

```
command =sh /webapps/trueguild_django/bin/gunicorn_start
```

It'll work.

Comment: you save my day

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have permission to execute gunicorn command under `trueguild`